# Some doubts about custom LWRP declaration

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I am doing my custom LWRP. But I have a doubt about it implementation.

I check into the bluepill, and I see that.

```
def load_current_resource
  @current_resource = Chef::Resource::BluepillService.new(new_resource.name)
  @current_resource.service_name(new_resource.service_name)

  Chef::Log.debug("Checking status of service #{new_resource.service_name}")

  determine_current_status!

  @current_resource
end
```

I see that in others cookbook and I want to do something like this.

```
def load_current_resource
   @current_resource = Chef::Resource::MyCustomLWRP.new(new_resource.name)
   @current_resource
end
```

But I can't find where I have to define Chef::Resource::MyCustomLWRP.

I want to do this with the goal of create an idempotent resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of steps you have to go through to create your own custom resource (LWRP). In summary it involves creating a file in a cookbooks `resources` directory and an identically named file in the `providers` directory.

The file you create in the `resources` directory defines (among other things) the actions and attributes which your custom resource can accept. The file you create in the `providers` directory provides implementations for each of the actions that are specified in the resources file.

The name of resource will be the cookbook name + the file name without the rb extension.

For more details, there is a great tutorial here: http://dougireton.com/blog/2012/12/31/creating-an-lwrp/